# "are gone" or "be gone"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

In the sentence below, can the expression "be gone" be used instead of "are gone"? According to the research I've done the correct, or more usual, would be to use "are gone" but for some reason the "be gone" option sounds much more natural to me.

*Tomorrow morning, when all the guests **are gone / be gone**, I will clean the house. For the moment I just want to enjoy my own party.*

Comment: Do you have any reason other than your feeling to think "be gone" is correct?

Comment: Sorry, I don't. Maybe because the option "be gone" is the option that sounds closest to the way we speak in Portuguese. So I was just wondering if using both forms would be acceptable, even though the use of "are gone" might be more correct or more commonly used.

Comment: In English, one might say "when all the guests **will** be gone", but that helper verb is required with *be*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the tense of the sentence. In this case, the expression "are gone" is correct. However, if the sentence tense was changed, you could add the helping verb "will" to make the sentence

> "Tomorrow morning, when all the guests *will be gone*, I will clean the
> house. For the moment I just want to enjoy my own party."

This sentence however does sound a bit awkward, though it is correct as well.

In short, *use "are" if the party is almost over*, and *use "will be" if it is not.*